# Convergences of Machin's Original Formula and Leibniz's Formula for $\pi$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, pi

Does anyone know why Machin's original formula for $\pi$ converges so much faster than Leibniz's formula for $\pi$?

Machin's original formula: $\pi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{16(-1)^n239^{2n+1}-4(-1)^n5^{2n+1}}{1195^{2n+1}(2n+1)}$

Leibniz's formula: $\pi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4(-1)^n}{2n+1}$

I think it has something to do with the centre of convergences, but am not sure.

Comment: For your curiosity, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula

Comment: It would be interesting to know the reason for this question to be downvoted and close-voted. It shows context AND an idea that might work.

Comment: In Machin's formula, it is not such a good idea to group the terms in a single fraction, as the terms with coefficient $239$ decrease faster and you need less of them (not counting that you require much larger numbers).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Breaking the current record in $\pi$-calculation will be extremely difficult, no matter which method is used. For the sine-function, we have a quickly converging series, so I cannot understand your argument below. And the formula for the $n-th$ digit is $(1)$ only in base $16$ and $(2)$ does not give the result "immediately" , just much faster than the direct calculation.

Comment: @Peter: for world record breaking, the sine series is extremely slow, having only linear convergence speed, which would lead to worse than $O(n^2)$ algorithms. Of course, world records will continue to be broken at a regular pace. I did mention that the BBP formula is base-16. *immediately* in the sense of without previous digits, don't be bad faith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formulas are based on the Taylor development of the arc tangent,

$$\sum_n\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.$$

The absolute ratio of successive terms is

$$\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}x^2.$$

So when $x=1$ (Leibnitz), the general term decreases desperately slowly, while in the Machin formula, it decreases by more than a factor $25$ on every new term, giving each time more than one exact digit.

---

There are much faster formulas (Machin isn't used anymore for the computation records), and even a formula that gives the $n^{th}$ digit without computing the previous (though in base $16$ only).

Answer (score 0):

Machin's formula is superior because the terms tend much more quickly to $0$ than the terms of Leibniz's formula.

The arctan-function has the expansion $$\arctan(x)=x-1/3x^3+1/5x^5-+\cdots$$ and the idea of Machin's formula is to cleverly combine values of the arctan-function with small arguments.

By the way : Very fast to $\pi$ converges the following sequence

$$x_1=3$$

$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\sin(x_n)$$

Comment: An additional advantage of this formula is that the initial values need not be computed accurately, errors will compensate later. Anyway, it is unusable for new records, because of the sine function.

Answer (score 0):

When you write Machin's formula as
$$
\pi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{16(-1)^n239^{2n+1}-4(-1)^n5^{2n+1}}{1195^{2n+1}(2n+1)} ,
$$
then you may well wonder where it came from.  But Machin used
$$
\frac{\pi}{4} = \arctan\frac{1}{5} - \arctan\frac{1}{239}
$$
and then applied the Tayor series of $\arctan$ evaluated at these two points.  Of course that Taylor series converges faster at $1/5$ than at $1$.

---

**Plug:**  I write this for undergraduates or advanced high school students.  (And 1987-era computers.) There is a discussion of the rate of convergence of the Machin series.

G. A. Edgar, "Pi: difficult or easy?"   *Math. Mag.* **60** (1987) 141--150.